# Implementing 2D vector syntax for accessing a 1D vector?

Tags: vector, syntax, rust, operator-overloading

I'm making a toy roguelike and have a `Level` structure for storing the game map, for which the most naive implementation is a 2D vector.

I'm following [this tutorial](http://tomassedovic.github.io/roguelike-tutorial/) which uses a `Vector` of `Vector`s, but states that for performance gains it's also possible to use a single `Vector` of size `MAP_HEIGHT * MAP_WIDTH`, and to access a tile at `(x, y)` one can simply access `map[y * MAP_WIDTH + x]`.

I'm trying to implement this faster method but using getters and setters is clunky, and public fields aren't that great either. I'd much prefer it to feel like a 2D vector.

In order to do that I need to implement the `Index` trait for my class, but I'm not sure how to get the result I want. Maybe by nesting the `impl`s? I really no idea.

Here is my code with a terrible attempt at implementing `Index` for my structure, which obviously won't work for my purposes because it's one dimensional:

```
const MAP_WIDTH: i32 = 80;
const MAP_HEIGHT: i32 = 45;

pub struct Level {
    map: Vec<Tile>,
}

impl Level {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Level { map: vec![Tile::empty(); (MAP_HEIGHT * MAP_WIDTH) as usize] }
    }
}

impl std::ops::Index<i32> for Level {
    type Output = Tile;
    fn index(&self, x: i32) -> &Self::Output {
        self[MAP_WIDTH + x]; // We have x and y values; how do we make this work?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, though not obvious.

First of all, I suggest having the `MAP_WIDTH` and `MAP_HEIGHT` in `usize`, as they are positive integers:

```
const MAP_WIDTH: usize = 80;
const MAP_HEIGHT: usize = 45;
```

Then you need to implement `Index` (and possibly `IndexMut`) to return a slice; in this case I'm assuming that you want the first coordinate to be the row:

```
impl std::ops::Index<usize> for Level {
    type Output = [Tile];

    fn index(&self, row: usize) -> &[Tile] {
        let start = MAP_WIDTH * row;
        &self.map[start .. start + MAP_WIDTH]
    }
}

impl std::ops::IndexMut<usize> for Level {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, row: usize) -> &mut [Tile] {
        let start = MAP_WIDTH * row;
        &mut self.map[start .. start + MAP_WIDTH]
    }
}
```

Then, when you index a `Level`, it first returns a slice with the applicable row; then you can index that slice with the column number.

Below is an example implementation with a substitute `Tile`:

```
const MAP_WIDTH: usize = 80;
const MAP_HEIGHT: usize = 45;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Tile {
    x: u32,
    y: u32
}

pub struct Level {
    map: Vec<Tile>,
}

impl Level {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Level { map: vec![Tile { x: 0, y: 0 }; (MAP_HEIGHT * MAP_WIDTH) as usize] }
    }
}

impl std::ops::Index<usize> for Level {
    type Output = [Tile];

    fn index(&self, row: usize) -> &[Tile] {
        let start = MAP_WIDTH * row;
        &self.map[start .. start + MAP_WIDTH]
    }
}

impl std::ops::IndexMut<usize> for Level {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, row: usize) -> &mut [Tile] {
        let start = MAP_WIDTH * row;
        &mut self.map[start .. start + MAP_WIDTH]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut lvl = Level::new(); 

    lvl[5][2] = Tile { x: 5, y: 2 };

    println!("{:?}", lvl[5][2]); // Tile { x: 5, y: 2 }
}
```

Comment: In my game `Tile`s store two `bool`s, `blocked` and `block_sight`. The info about their position is in `Vector` itself. But thanks for the help. I think I'll just use a tuple for now as it's easier for me to understand, but I will definitely save this snippet for later use.

Comment: @Boiethios you're right, this actually solves the problem I asked about, so I'll accept this answer even though I'll be using tuples.

Comment: You should be aware that by doing this, you are **forever** requiring that your internal data structure be something that is based on slices. For example, you cannot use a "sparse" structure like a `HashMap` because it cannot return a `&[Tile]`. The ability to return a `&[Tile]` is now a part of the **public API** of the struct. It's certainly a possibility that the representation will change, especially since OP has already changed the representation once.

Comment: @Shepmaster If this is an issue, the OP just needs to create its own struct `Row` that implements `Index`: `Level` --index--> `Row` --index--> `Tile`.

Answer (score 6):

Make your struct indexible over objects of type `(i32, i32)`.

```
type Pos = (i32, i32);

impl std::ops::Index<Pos> for Level {
    type Output = Tile;
    fn index(&self, (x, y): Pos) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.map[(y * MAP_WIDTH + x) as usize]
    }
}
```

Which you can then access with, for example:

```
let tile = level[(3, 4)];
```

Since you are using `i32`, you need to make sure that the values are within range, and can be coerced to `usize`, which is what `Vec`s are indexed over. Probably you should just stick with `u32` or `usize` values from the start. Otherwise, you'll need to keep track of the minimum `x` and `y` values, and subtract them, to keep the position in range. It's definitely simpler to deal with positive coordinates and make the assumption that the corner of your map is `(0, 0)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're right, since `libtcod` maps `0,0` to the top left corner of the screen (meaning you can't, or rather don't want to go below `0,0`) I should use `u32` instead if `i32`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this without exposing internal details about your implementation. `Index` is defined as:

```
pub trait Index<Idx> 
where
    Idx: ?Sized, 
{
    type Output: ?Sized;
    fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output;
}
```

In order to support `game[x][y]`, the return value of `game[x]` would need to:

1. Be a reference to something. (`&Self::Output`)
2. Implement `Index` itself.

There's no value to return a reference to other than `self`, and `self` would already implement `Index` for a `usize` so you can't reuse it.

Instead, you can implement indexing for a tuple:

```
impl std::ops::Index<(usize, usize)> for Level {
    type Output = Tile;
    fn index(&self, (x, y): (usize, usize)) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.map[MAP_WIDTH as usize * y + x]
    }
}
```

This can be used as `level[(43, 12)]`.

---

If you [implement `Index` to return a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46547122/155423), you should be aware that you are **forever** requiring that your internal data structure be something that is based on slices. For example, you cannot use a "sparse" structure like a `HashMap` because it cannot return a `&[Tile]`. The ability to return a `&[Tile]` is now a part of the **public API** of the struct. It's certainly a possibility that the representation will change, especially since it's already changed once.